# Arch linux doesn't detect new ssd

Tags: linux, ssd, arch-linux

I just bought a new Kingston ssd for my old laptop, model PackardBell MZ35.

I'm trying to install ArchLinux on it, but it doesn't show on `fdisk`.

I boot the OS using a usb pendrive. If I enter the bios before booting, I can see both drives there, the usb and the new ssd.

However, when the system boots, `fdisk` only shows `/dev/sda`, which is the usb drive.

`blkid` also shows only the usb drive.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to see both drives in BIOS and considering your laptop is quite old I'd suggest the following:

1. Try to update BIOS
2. If your SSD is connected via adapter try
   connecting it to the main SATA port while connecting HDD via the
   said adapter

**EDIT:** I've missed that you can only see your USB drive when the system boots, that said your drives aren't initiated. What does `lsblk`list?
Try initiating them via `cfdisk` which is also usable for partitioning.

**EDIT2:** Also check if SATA operates in AHCI mode

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've been looking for it but haven't found any trustworthy site to download a BIOS update, right now I have phoenixbios v0.22.

Yep, SSD is connected to the SATA, this laptop only has one port.

Nop, `lsblk` and `cfdisk` don't show the SSD either, only the USB drive.

I have no AHCI option anywhere, the bios is super basic and practically only have options to set the hour, change boot order and some weird USB compatibility mode that I have tried on and off already.

Comment: I hate to say it but it looks like your laptop is way too old for proper SATA support :(

some kind of proof of it is here: https://www.mrmemory.co.uk/ssd-upgrades/packard-bell/easynote/mz35

Comment: I'm afraid you are right. Such a shame, it had a really nice screen